# Is there a testFinished listener method in testng?

Tags: java, testing, automated-tests, testng, actionlistener

The method `onFinish(ITestContext context)` is invoked after all the tests and configuration methods have run.

I'm searching an equivalent method which is invoked after a **single** test **and** all of it's **configuration methods**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess you are looking for [IInvokedMethodListener](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/IInvokedMethodListener.html)..

Answer (score 0):

A method annotated with Junit's @after will be run after each method is run, you can also use @afterClass to be run after the who unit test class. For example

```
@Before
public final void setUp() { //Set up some data to use }

@After
public final void tearDown() { //remove the data }
```

Comment: thx for the answer, but that's not what i'm want. I'm searching a TestNG listener, who is invoked after test method and configuration methods (etc. after, before).

Answer (score 0):

According to [Dependency injection](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#native-dependency-injection) section of TestNG documentation, you can specify a parameter of type `java.lang.reflect.Method`:

> Any @BeforeMethod (and @AfterMethod) can declare a parameter of type
>   java.lang.reflect.Method. This parameter will receive the test method
>   that will be called once this @BeforeMethod finishes (or after the
>   method as run for @AfterMethod).